# Finding the right input & output shape for a conv1D Keras NN

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, input, conv-neural-network

I build a LSTM model to analyse timeseries with an input matrix X of size (1750, 20, 28) with 1750  a length sequence 20 and 28 features. In fact, I take my original X matrix with 28 features and create a 3D matrix with a sliding window of length 20. The y matrix is of size (1750,)
I used it successfully with a LTSM (input shape = X_train[1], X_train[2])

It works perfectly well with a first layer model.add(layer_LSTM1) or with a stacked LSTM, but it does not give great results (very unstable if I run twice the same NN).
I then try to apply a conv1D NN on the same dataset, with an identical input shape. I get an error message that I present below.
Here is the model definition and the messages :

```
# available layers
layer_drop = keras.layers.Dropout(rate = dropout)
layer_dense1 = Dense(units= layer_1, activation = 'relu')
layer_LSTM1 = keras.layers.LSTM(units=layer_1, activation = 'relu' , return_sequences = False, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2]))
layer_LSTMstack1 = keras.layers.LSTM(units=layer_2, activation = 'relu' , return_sequences = True, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2]))
layer_LSTMstack2 = keras.layers.LSTM(units=layer_2, activation = 'relu' , return_sequences = True)
layer_LSTMstackend = keras.layers.LSTM(units=layer_2, activation = 'relu')
layer_conv1D1 = keras.layers.Conv1D(filters = 28, kernel_size= 3, activation = 'relu', input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2]))
layer_output = Dense(units = 1)

# Model architecture 
model.add(layer_conv1D1)
model.add(layer_dense1)
model.add(layer_output)
```

I get the following feedback (to which I added the model.summary()

```
 runfile('C:/GD/AI/Conv1D_1stock.py', wdir='C:/GD/AI')
Reloaded modules: util_prepa, util_model, util_DENSE
Time preparing data =  Time: 3.784785270690918
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\GD\AI\Conv1D_1stock.py", line 133, in <module>
    model, history = compile_train_model(model, loss, optimizer, X_train, y_train, epochs, batch_size, validation_split, verbose)

  File "C:\GD\AI\util_LSTM.py", line 89, in compile_train_model
    history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = epochs, batch_size = batch_size, validation_split = validation_split, verbose = verbose)

  File "C:\Users\Nav\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 709, in fit
    shuffle=shuffle)

  File "C:\Users\Nav\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 2692, in _standardize_user_data
    y, self._feed_loss_fns, feed_output_shapes)

  File "C:\Users\Nav\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training_utils.py", line 549, in check_loss_and_target_compatibility
    ' while using as loss `' + loss_name + '`. '

ValueError: A target array with shape (1750, 1) was passed for an output of shape (None, 18, 1) while using as loss `mean_squared_error`. This loss expects targets to have the same shape as the output.


print(model.summary())
Model: "sequential_10"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv1d_7 (Conv1D)            (None, 18, 28)            2380      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_26 (Dense)             (None, 18, 128)           3712      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_28 (Dense)             (None, 18, 1)             129       
=================================================================
Total params: 6,221
Trainable params: 6,221
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

What am I doing wrong ? Could someone indicate me the right direction ?
Thanks a lot in advance.

NB. As requested, here are the parameters that I use (code since the beginning - sorry if it is long) :

```
# ====  PART 0. Installing libraries ============
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3 as sq
import time
from itertools import chain
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import seaborn as sns
from pylab import rcParams
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rc
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Bidirectional, Dropout, Activation, Dense, LSTM, Flatten, ConvLSTM2D
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import CuDNNLSTM
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from util_prepa import *
from util_model import *
from util_LSTM import *

start_time = time.time()
rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 14, 8

### ====   PART 0.A Defining hyeprparameters & parameters  =  INPUT REQUIRED ============
## SQL parameters
dbInput = 'Inputlist.db'           ### Database with input data
dbList = "TRlistInput"              ### table with list of datasets
ric = "ATOS"                        ### RIC code of the underlying item
dbOutput = 'saveLSTMoutput.db'       ### Database for saving output
saveX = "savX"                     ### Table for saving X output in dbOutput
saveY = "savY"                     ### Table for saving Y output in dbOutput

## Dataset parameters
horiz = 10                          ### time horizon of the prediction 
seq_length = 20                     ### number of days for enriching the LSTM
step = 1                            ### time lag within LSTM memory batch

tested_model = 'Conv1D'           ### 'LSTM' / 'STACKED' / 'ConvLSTM' / 'BAYES' / 'Conv1D' / 'Conv2D' / DEEP'

## Parameters LSTM & CNN
drop_rows = 50                      ### Number of unrelevant rows given technical indicators computation
lstmStart = 0                    ### initial value of X and Y matrices out of the total dataset
lstmSize = 2000                     ### length of the X & Y matrices starting from lstmStart index
proportionTrain = 0.875 

X_plot = 0                          ### 1 for plot close price  /  0 for no plot

### ====   PART 1.A Connecting to SQL DB and loading lists ============
dataX, dataY = get_model_data(dbInput, dbList, ric, horiz, drop_rows)
dataX = get_model_cleanXset(dataX, trigger)                             # Clean X matrix for insufficient data
Xs, ys = LSTM_create_dataset(dataX, dataY, seq_length, step)

(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test), (res_train, res_test) = LSTM_train_test_size(Xs, ys, lstmStart, lstmSize, proportionTrain)
(X_train, X_test), (train_mean, train_std) = get_model_scaleX(X_train, X_test)

### ====   PART 2.B Input & define Model  =  INPUT REQUIRED ============
## Model & Hyper-parameters
validation_split = 0.1
model = keras.Sequential()
dropout = 0.1
optimizer = 'adam'               ### Optimizer of the compiled model
learning = 0.001
loss = 'mean_squared_error'
verbose = 0                      ### 0 = hidden computation  //  1 = computation printed
batch_size = 32
epochs = 15
layer_1 = 128
layer_2 = 256

# available layers
layer_drop = keras.layers.Dropout(rate = dropout)
layer_dense1 = Dense(units= layer_1, activation = 'relu')
layer_dense2 = Dense(units= layer_2, activation = 'relu')
layer_LSTM1 = keras.layers.LSTM(units=layer_1, activation = 'relu' , return_sequences = False, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2]))
layer_LSTMstack1 = keras.layers.LSTM(units=layer_2, activation = 'relu' , return_sequences = True, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2]))
layer_LSTMstack2 = keras.layers.LSTM(units=layer_2, activation = 'relu' , return_sequences = True)
layer_LSTMstackend = keras.layers.LSTM(units=layer_2, activation = 'relu')
layer_conv1D1 = keras.layers.Conv1D(filters = 28, kernel_size= 3, activation = 'relu', input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2]))
layer_output = Dense(units = 1)

# Model architecture 
model.add(layer_conv1D1)
model.add(layer_dense1)
model.add(layer_output)
model_arch = 'LSTM1-128+D1-128+Out'

### ====   PART 4.B Compile and Train model + predict   ============
model, history = compile_train_model(model, loss, optimizer, X_train, y_train, epochs, batch_size, validation_split, verbose)
eval_train, eval_test, y_pred = model_predict(model, history, X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test, res_test)

plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('model loss')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Have you posted the line that failed? I would expect that error when you do a model.fit?

Comment: Yeah, write a code which outputs the error.

Comment: In fact, I don't know where it fails. I can add the parameters that I use as appendix

Comment: Here is the error line when I run the program :

Answer (score 0):

First, lets discuss input shape. My interpretation of "input matrix X of size (1750, 20, 28)" means you have a Batch Size of 1750, a 1D series of 20 time steps with 28 features per time step.

When you add a convolutional layer, the Batch Size stays the same, the number of time steps stays generally the same (it depends on how your filter fits the time steps) and your number of features output will equal the number of filters you used.

So when you add a dense layer after the convolution, you are adding a 2D dense layer ( the same weights are applied to each feature vector per time step). To avoid this, you need to add `keras.layers.Flatten()` somewhere in your code. Flatten will take your 2D convolutional output and put it into 1D. To get the effect I think you are going for here, I would modify the code like this

```
model.add(layer_conv1D1)
model.add(layer_dense1)
model.add(keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(layer_output)
```

Comment: That is exactly the right answer (but the flattening comes before the dense layer)
Thanks. a lot !

Comment: I did it but as I am a newbee with few voted questions, my vote doesn't appear publicly. Sorry for this

Comment: No need to be sorry for having to follow the rules!